# Как сделать код более универсальным (фильтрация массива)?

Tags: javascript

Имеется вот такой код, который производит фильтрацию массива по заданным параметрам и выводит результат в консоль. В данном случае код выполняет выборку по значению color со свойством red и number со свойством 10 в объектах, которые наполняют массив.

Код работает, но проблема возникнет, например, когда чек-боксов будет больше двух. Пробовал использовать цикл, но ничего не получилось. Помогите доработать код, чтобы не было необходимости перечислять инпуты по индексу, т.е. чтобы была одна функция, которая бы выполняла общую задачу.

```js
var colorsAndNumbers = [{
    color: 'red',
    number: 10
  },

  {
    color: 'yellow',
    number: 10
  },

  {
    color: 'red',
    number: 5
  },

  {
    color: 'black',
    number: 5
  },

  {
    color: 'red',
    number: 5
  }
]

var form = document.querySelector('.filters');
var inputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.filters input'));

var formChangeHandler = function() {

  var newList = colorsAndNumbers.filter(function(item) {
    if (inputs[0].checked) {
      return item.color === inputs[0].value;
    } else {
      return item;
    }
  }).

  filter(function(item) {
    if (inputs[1].checked) {
      return item.number === +inputs[1].value;
    } else {
      return item;
    }
  });

  console.log(newList);
}

form.addEventListener('change', formChangeHandler);
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <form action="#" class="filters">
    <input type="checkbox" name="features" value="red" id="color">
    <label class="feature" for="color">Color Red</label>

    <input type="checkbox" name="features" value="10" id="number">
    <label for="number">Number 10</label>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Я поражаюсь – вы пометили верным ответ, который не только **не работает**, но даже при правках ошибок в коде **не выполняет поставленной задачи**. Вам так никто отвечать не будет при таком поведении! **Почитайте справку**: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас есть массив инпутов, каждый со своим `id`, которое схоже с ключом фильтруемого св-ва. От этого и можно двигаться

```js
const colorsAndNumbers = [{
    color: 'red',
    number: 10
  },

  {
    color: 'yellow',
    number: 10
  },

  {
    color: 'red',
    number: 5
  },

  {
    color: 'black',
    number: 5
  },

  {
    color: 'red',
    number: 5
  }
]

const form = document.querySelector('.filters');
const inputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.filters input'));

const applyFilter = (input, data) => (
  input.value == data[input.id];
);

const formChangeHandler = () => {
  // получаем список инпутов, по которым нужно отфильтровать
  const filters = inputs
    .filter(input => input.checked);

  // для каждого элемента в data применяем фильтр из инпутов
  // и если хотя бы один фильтр вернул false значит убираем элемент
  const newList = colorsAndNumbers.filter(data => {
    for(let f in filters) {
       if(!applyFilter(filters[f], data)) return false;
    }
    
    return true;
  });

  console.log(newList);
}

form.addEventListener('change', formChangeHandler);
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <form action="#" class="filters">
    <input type="checkbox" name="features" value="red" id="color">
    <label class="feature" for="color">Color Red</label>

    <input type="checkbox" name="features" value="10" id="number">
    <label for="number">Number 10</label>
  </form>
</div>
```